# Using regex in python to find matching strings from a multiline variable

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to grab some data from a variable. It is in a multiline. Currently, my output is empty. Thanks in advance.

```
    test = re.findall("0x\sN/A",newMessage,re.MULTILINE)
    print ("test ", test)
```

Sample Data:

```
 New token

Version: V2

Pair: WBNB-WCH
Liquidity: 22.0000 BNB ($8284.1997)   #-- data to grab
ℹ️ Transaction

Name: WCH
Total Supply: 1,000,000,000 WCH
Token Price: 0.0000 BNB ($0.0000)     #-- data to grab

Holders: 1
Transfers: 1

⛓ BscScan

 Swap on PancakeSwap

➡️ poocoin.app

0xe61cDdDdF26Ac94C214C981FA012AcA805ea4b4D     #-- data to grab
-----------------------------------
Our Chat - YourCryptoHelperChat
Our Main Info Channel - YourCryptoHelper
```

Current Output:

```
test  []
```

Wanted Output:

```
0xe61cDdDdF26Ac94C214C981FA012AcA805ea4b4D
Liquidity: 22.0000 BNB ($8284.1997)
Token Price: 0.0000 BNB ($0.0000)
```

Comment: If you need three lines, why even try `0x\sN/A`? What is the rule here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assumed your case is simple. So this is simple solution to find:

- Starts with `Liquidity:`
- Starts with `Token Price:`
- Starts with `0x`

```py
import re
find = r"^(Liquidity: .+|Token Price: .+|0x.+)"
test = re.findall(find, value, re.MULTILINE)
for ret in test:
  print (ret)
```

```
Result:
Liquidity: 22.0000 BNB ($8284.1997)
Token Price: 0.0000 BNB ($0.0000)
0xe61cDdDdF26Ac94C214C981FA012AcA805ea4b4D
```

https://regex101.com/r/1fqORj/1

https://trinket.io/python/99b59d62b8

Comment: Im trying to add the Name: using *r"^(Name:.+|Liquidity: .+|Token Price: .+|0x.+)"* and produces the result only that, the Name appears second. Im expecting it will be the first since its the first in the argument.

Comment: @rbutrnz You cannot change order with regular expression only. But you can change order using `sorted` function. In this link, you can change order by changing number in replace function. https://trinket.io/python/b0d1c262bb

Answer (score 1):

```
regex = r"Liquidity: ([^#]*).*Token Price: ([^#]*).*(0x[\da-fA-F]{40})"
matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)
```